# Bad request error in Flask while request names generated with javascript

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

I'm creating an app to calculate a projection of the transit given the years and some other values, first I created a script in javascript where depending on if the user decide to add a new type of vehicle a new `div` is created with unique ids and names and ofcourse the data the user introduced, for showing the final result i'm using ajax, the problem comes when i tried to access the data via flask, i'm getting a bad request from the names of each vehicle like if they did not exist, but the page is actually displaying them (hope you understand my english and my problem :) )

I've tried giving a specific name (a1) an then tried to take the value in flask but i still can#t make it work.
Python

```py
@app.route("/pavimentos/calculoTransito" , methods=['POST'])
def calculoTransito():
    direc = float(request.form["direc"])
    zr = float(request.form["zr"])
    years  = float(request.form["years"])
    tc = float(request.form["direc"])
    vehicles = int(request.form["vehicles"])
    car1 = request.form.get("a1", None)
    if car1==None:
        print("No funciona")
    else:
        print("Funciona")
```

always get "No funciona"

Javascript

```
countClicks = 0
lista_vehiculos = []
function addVehicle(){
    countClicks += 1;

    //var automovil = document.getElementById("automovil").value
    var fd = document.getElementById("damage_factor").value
    var currentType = document.getElementById("vehicleType")

    if(currentType.value == 1){
        var icon = "<h2 class='pt-4'><i class='fas fa-car text-secondary'></i></h2>";
        var tipoVehiculo = "Automóvil";
    }

    ... More code for select the currentType ...    

    var vehicleStyle = "<div><input id=a" + countClicks + "name=a" + countClicks + "value=" + fd  + "></div>"

    lista_vehiculos.push(vehicleStyle)

    var vehicle = document.getElementById("vehiclesContainer").innerHTML += lista_vehiculos[countClicks-1]

    document.getElementById("vehicles").value = countClicks

}
```

AJAX part

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').on('submit', function(event){
        $.ajax({
            data:{
                direc: $('#direc').val(),
                zr: $('#zr').val(),
                years: $('#years').val(),
                tc: $('#growingRate').val(),
                vehicles: $('#vehicles').val(),
                car1: $('#a1').val()
            },
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/pavimentos/calculoTransito'
        })
        .done(function(data){
            if (data.resultado){
                $('#resultado').text(data.resultado).show()
            }
        })

        event.preventDefault();

    });
});
```

Comment: We can't help here unless we see something from the JavaScript side. Additionally, `vehicles` isn't defined in the code you've shown

Comment: I don't get it. That JS doesn't include a form or any attempt to communicate with Flask. What is it supposed to clarify?

Comment: I answered and then realised that you've cargo-culted too much. _There is no form_, so why do you have `$('form').on('submit', function(event){`?

Comment: Hi! @roganjosh, the form is in another html file and has its own flask route

Answer (score 0):

You're not submitting a form, you're sending JSON. The initial event might be the submission of a form, but your AJAX uses `event.preventDefault()` and does not end up submitting a traditional serialized form. You can't use `car1 = request.form.get("a1", None)` here.

Firstly, you should correct your AJAX to add a `contentType`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').on('submit', function(event){
        $.ajax({
            data: JSON.stringify({
                direc: $('#direc').val(),
                zr: $('#zr').val(),
                years: $('#years').val(),
                tc: $('#growingRate').val(),
                vehicles: $('#vehicles').val(),
                car1: $('#a1').val()
            }),
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            url: '/pavimentos/calculoTransito'
        })
        .done(function(data){
            if (data.resultado){
                $('#resultado').text(data.resultado).show()
            }
        })

        event.preventDefault();

    });
});
```

And then you need to change your Flask method from `request.form` to `request.json`. So the Flask side would look something like:

```
@app.route("/pavimentos/calculoTransito" , methods=['POST'])
def calculoTransito():
    req = request.json
    direc = float(req["direc"])
    zr = float(req["zr"])
    ...
    car1 = req.get("a1", None)
    if car1 is None: # None is a singleton, you shouldn't use == here
        print("No funciona")
    else:
        print("Funciona")
```

*LATE EDIT*

This can't work because `calculoTransito` does not actually `return` anything, so Flask will throw an error from that alone. Your view function actually has to return something other than an implicit `None`.